# Azure Authenticating Service Principal with certificate for service bus

Tags: azure, service, azureservicebus, service-principal

I am hoping to use a windows service installed on client machines to talk to an azure service bus. Please note that the service is not installed on the cloud it is on premises.

During my testing I can

1. Add items to the queue using the default identity (taking my VS settings)
2. Add items to the queue using SAS - i want a bit more security, using and endpoint connection string
3. Add items to a queue using client, tenant and secret using ClientSecretCredentials

but I cannot find anywhere if I can use a certificate to authenticate a service principal.

It a certificate a good way to go? Are there any better alternatives?

Comment: Please see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.clientcertificatecredential?view=azure-dotnet.

Comment: I don’t suppose there are any working examples rather than just the class definition?

Comment: Samples for using the `ClientCertificateCredential` can be found [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity/samples/ClientCertificateCredentialSamples.md).

Comment: Great thanks, what i dont understand is you still need a tenant and client id. surely that is still pretty unsecure. Where do you store the tenant and client ID on premisis, surely not in a config file.

Comment: The tenant and client are necessary for AAD to handle the request.  Typically, we'd recommend using Key Vault or another secure enclave to encrypt and store secrets.  That said; we're at the edge of my knowledge.   You may want to consider opening an issue in the [Azure SDK for .NET repository](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues) which would let the folks responsible for  the `Azure.Identity` package weigh in with their advice.